# Display only some of the page numbers by django pagination

Tags: django, django-pagination

I am using the django paginator in the template. Its working ok, but not good when there's large numbers of pages.

views.py:

```
def blog(request):
    blogs_list = Blog.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(blogs_list, 1)

    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except:
        page = 1

    try:
        blogs = paginator.page(page)
    except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        blogs = paginator.page(page)
    return render(request, 'blogs.html', {
        'blogs':blogs
        })
```

snippet of the template:

```
  <div class="prev_next">

    {% if blogs.has_previous %}
      <a class="prev btn btn-info" href="?page={{blogs.previous_page_number}}">Prev</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if blogs.has_next %}
      <a class="next btn btn-info" href="?page={{blogs.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="pages">
      <ul>
      {% for pg in blogs.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if blogs.number == pg %}
          <li><a href="?page={{pg}}" class="btn btn-default">{{pg}}</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li><a href="?page={{pg}}" class="btn">{{pg}}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="clear_both"></span>

  </div>
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

What do I do to display only 7 page numbers and not all of it ranging from the current page number, like this:

```
Prev 1 (2) 3 4 5 Next
```

I hope I was clear, if not please ask. Your help and guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First of all I would change the following:

```
try:
    blogs = paginator.page(page)
except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
    blogs = paginator.page(page)  # Raises the same error
```

But you could pass a range within your context.

```
index = paginator.page_range.index(blogs.number)
max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
start_index = index - 3 if index >= 3 else 0
end_index = index + 3 if index <= max_index - 3 else max_index
page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]
```

Now you should be able to loop over the range to construct the right links with `?page=`.

=== Edit ===
So your view would be something like this:

```
def blog(request):
    paginator = Paginator(Blog.objects.all(), 1)

    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except:
        page = 1

    try:
        blogs = paginator.page(page)
    except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        blogs = paginator.page(1)

    # Get the index of the current page
    index = blogs.number - 1  # edited to something easier without index
    # This value is maximum index of your pages, so the last page - 1
    max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
    # You want a range of 7, so lets calculate where to slice the list
    start_index = index - 3 if index >= 3 else 0
    end_index = index + 3 if index <= max_index - 3 else max_index
    # Get our new page range. In the latest versions of Django page_range returns 
    # an iterator. Thus pass it to list, to make our slice possible again.
    page_range = list(paginator.page_range)[start_index:end_index]

    return render(request, 'blogs.html', {
        'blogs': blogs,
        'page_range': page_range,
    })
```

So now we have to edit your template to accept our new list of page numbers:

```
<div class="prev_next">
    {% if blogs.has_previous %}
        <a class="prev btn btn-info" href="?page={{blogs.previous_page_number}}">Prev</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if blogs.has_next %}
        <a class="next btn btn-info" href="?page={{blogs.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="pages">
        <ul>
        {% for pg in page_range %}
            {% if blogs.number == pg %}
                <li><a href="?page={{pg}}" class="btn btn-default">{{pg}}</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="?page={{pg}}" class="btn">{{pg}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="clear_both"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get you. Could you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @Robin, see my changes.

Comment: Exception: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice' on page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]

Comment: @RaymondSeger, this is because Django changed its functionality, in older functions paginator.page_range was a list, now it returns an iterator. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 97):

Gonna throw this in. I came up with it because it lets you know there are more pages on either side.

```
<ul class="pagination">

{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
{% else %}
    <li class="disabled"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
{% endif %}

{% if page_obj.number|add:'-4' > 1 %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:'-5' }}">&hellip;</a></li>
{% endif %}

{% for i in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if page_obj.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
    {% elif i > page_obj.number|add:'-5' and i < page_obj.number|add:'5' %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if page_obj.paginator.num_pages > page_obj.number|add:'4' %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:'5' }}">&hellip;</a></li>
{% endif %}

{% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
{% else %}
    <li class="disabled"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
{% endif %}

</ul>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Paging with elipses]

Comment: Excellent answer !! Based on this answer I created a templatetag with the same result.

Comment: Awesome! This is also working with generic class based views.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for sharing this, this saved me from using a package or having to wrap my brain around this. (Used on Django 2.2)

Comment: This is awesome!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: how to responsive that for mobile?

Comment: @EbrahimAbdollahian you could use a css framework, such as Bootstrap (v5 as of this comment), embed the above within `<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12"></div></div>` to get present responsively. The example used is very generic.

Answer (score 54):

Another shorter solution with template is compare current forloop.counter with certain range.

with bootstrap I use this template

> ```
> <nav aria-label="Page navigation">   <ul class="pagination">
> {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
> <li class="page-item">
>   <a class="page-link" href="?page=1" aria-label="Previous">
>     <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
>     <span class="sr-only">begin</span>
>   </a>
> </li>   {% endif %}
>
> {% for n in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
>   {% if page_obj.number == n %}
>     <li class="page-item active">
>       <span class="page-link">{{ n }}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>
>     </li>
>   {% elif n > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and n < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
>     <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ n }}">{{ n }}</a></li>
>   {% endif %}
> {% endfor %}
>
> {% if page_obj.has_next %}
>   <li class="page-item">
>     <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}" aria-label="Next">
>       <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
>       <span class="sr-only">end</span>
>     </a>
>   </li>
>   {% endif %}   </ul> </nav>
> ```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I liked this answer best, much shorter and easier to understand\

Comment: This is the simpliest approach.It helped me, Thank you very much

Comment: (to avoid duplicate first and last page in between pages) Line 15 replace with:
 ` {% if n != 1 and n != page_obj.paginator.num_pages %} <li class="page-item "><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ n }}">{{ n }</a</li> {% endif %} `

Comment: this is wise amazing answer very very very simple solution to complex problem

Comment: Simple approach helped me lot. Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

I found the simplest thing to do was to create a pagination snippet that just shows the pages you want it to.

In my case I didn't want any previous or next links. I just wanted to always have a link to the first and last pages and then have the current page and the two pages either side of the current page.

My template snippet (uses variables from django-tables2 - variables will have slightly different names if you're using a Django `Paginator` directly)

```
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load i18n %}

{% if table.page %}
  {% with table.page.paginator.count as total %}
    {% with table.page.number as page_num %}
      {% with table.page.paginator.num_pages as num_pages %}
        {% block pagination %}
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">    
              {% if table.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
                <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                  {% for n in table.page.paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if table.page.number|add:'-3' == n %}
                      {# First page #}
                      <li><a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_page_field=1 %}">1</a></li>
                      {% if n != 1 %}
                        <li class="disabled"><a>&#8943;</a></li>
                      {% endif %}
                    {% elif table.page.number == n %}
                      {# Current page #}
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">{{ n }}</a></li>
                    {% elif table.page.number|add:'-3' < n and n < table.page.number|add:'3' %}
                      {# Pages around current page #}
                      <li><a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_page_field=n %}">{{ n }}</a></li>
                    {% elif table.page.number|add:'3' == n %}
                      {# Last page #}
                      {% if n != num_pages %}
                        <li class="disabled"><a>&#8943;</a></li>
                      {% endif %}
                      <li><a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_page_field=num_pages %}">{{ num_pages }}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endblock pagination %}
      {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

Examples of what my pagination looks like at different pages

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

Credit: this was inspired by [@Pavel1114's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45717542/8138241).

Answer (score 6):

Django 3.2 introduces [a new feature on the Paginator class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.get_elided_page_range):

```
Paginator.get_elided_page_range(number, *, on_each_side=3, on_ends=2)
```

> With the default values for `on_each_side` and `on_ends`, if the current page is 10 and there are 50 pages, the page range will be `[1, 2, '…', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, '…', 49, 50]`.

Comment: Using `get_elided_page_range` as a template tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69277936/how-to-use-get-elided-page-range-in-django-paginator

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code.

```
     <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">

            <li class="page-item {% if not page_obj.has_previous %} disabled {% endif %}">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page=1" tabindex="-1">FIRST</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item {% if not page_obj.has_previous %} disabled {% endif %}">
                <a class="page-link" href="{% if page_obj.has_previous %}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{% endif %} " tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
            </li>

            {% if page_obj.number|add:'-4' > 1 %}
                <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:'-5' }}">&hellip;</a></li>
            {% endif %}

            {% for i in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                    <li class="active page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                {% elif i > page_obj.number|add:'-5' and i < page_obj.number|add:'5' %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% if page_obj.paginator.num_pages > page_obj.number|add:'4' %}
                <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:'5' }}">&hellip;</a></li>
            {% endif %}

            <li class="page-item {% if not page_obj.has_next %} disabled {% endif %}">
                <a class="page-link" href="{% if page_obj.has_next %} ?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }} {% endif %}">Next</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item {% if not page_obj.has_next %} disabled {% endif %}">
                <a class="page-link" href="{% if page_obj.has_next %} ?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}  {% endif %}">LAST</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on the current page, number links with page number displayed is not constant. if current page is 1: 5 links are displayed, if current page is 5 or more 9 links are displayed. How to display the same number of links?

Answer (score 3):

You could also extend `Paginator` class.

```
class BootstrapPaginator(Paginator):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """        
        :param wing_pages: How many pages will be shown before and after current page.
        """
        self.wing_pages = kwargs.pop('wing_pages', 3)
        super(BootstrapPaginator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _get_page(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.page = super(BootstrapPaginator, self)._get_page(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.page

    @property
    def page_range(self):
        return range(max(self.page.number - self.wing_pages, 1),
                     min(self.page.number + self.wing_pages + 1, self.num_pages + 1))
```

Then in template:

```
{% for num in action_list.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if action_list.number == num %}
         <li class="active"><a href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
         <li><a href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now `page_range` will only consist of 7 items. `wing_pages` + current page + `wing_pages`[custom django paginator for bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk95J.png)

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [@Pavel1114](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45717542/8138241) and [@Inti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46003749/8138241). Removed the arrow at the beginning and at the end as they are not that useful. Added The first page and last page for faster accessing.

```
<ul>
  <li class="grp-results">
      <span>{{paginator.count}} total</span>
  </li>
  {% if data.number|add:'-4' > 1 %}
    <li><a href="?page=1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page={{ data.number|add:'-5' }}">&hellip;</a></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% for i in data.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if data.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }}</span></li>
    {% elif i > data.number|add:'-3' and i < data.number|add:'3' %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if data.paginator.num_pages > data.number|add:'4' %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ data.number|add:'5' }}">&hellip;</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page={{ data.paginator.count }}">{{ data.paginator.count }}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did it only on templates with expressions:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    <div class="text-center">
        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
            {% if page_obj.number >= 5 %}
            <li><a href="?page=1">1</a></li>
            <li><span>...</span></li>
            {% elif page_obj.number == 4 %}
            <li><a href="?page=1">1</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if page_obj.number|add:"-2" >= 1  %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:"-2" }}">{{ page_obj.number|add:"-2" }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if page_obj.number|add:"-1" >= 1  %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:"-1" }}">{{ page_obj.number|add:"-1" }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            <li class="active"><a href="?page={{ page_obj.number }}">{{ page_obj.number }}</a></li>
            {% if page_obj.number|add:"1" <= paginator.num_pages  %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:"1" }}">{{ page_obj.number|add:"1" }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if page_obj.number|add:"2" <= paginator.num_pages %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:"2" }}">{{ page_obj.number|add:"2" }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if page_obj.number|add:"2" <= paginator.num_pages|add:"-2" %}
            <li><span>...</span></li>
            <li><a href="?page={{ paginator.num_pages }}">{{ paginator.num_pages }}</a></li>
            {% elif page_obj.number|add:"1" <= paginator.num_pages|add:"-2" %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ paginator.num_pages }}">{{ paginator.num_pages }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I know django is like "dont write your code again" but i found this easier for me to understand right now. Hope i helped.